# NSMutableArray to NSUserDefaults and then retrieving it iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

The code below can be used five times a day. Every time whenever a new value will be created it is to be saved in `NSMutableArray` and the previous values should not be deleted from there.

Is it possible?

```
if ([day isEqualToString:@"f"]) {

        if ([name isEqualToString:@"f"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f1"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }
        else if ([name isEqualToString:@"z"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f2"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }
        else if ([name isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f3"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }
        else if ([name isEqualToString:@"m"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f4"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }
        else if ([name isEqualToString:@"i"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f5"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }

    }
```

Like in this code if `NSString F1` is saved in my `friArray`, next time the value might be `f2, f3, f4 or f5`. Now when I shall be retrieving the array from `NSUserdefaults`. It should have all the values saved in it.

How can I achieve this?

```
EDITED:
```

I have tried it like this but it is giving me `friarray::(null)`. What can be the issue?

```
NSUserDefaults *day1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    friArray = [[day1 objectForKey:@"frArr"] mutableCopy];

    name = @"f";

    if ([day isEqualToString:@"f"]) {

        if ([name isEqualToString:@"f"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f1"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }
        else if ([name isEqualToString:@"z"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f2"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }
        else if ([name isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f3"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }
        else if ([name isEqualToString:@"m"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f4"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }
        else if ([name isEqualToString:@"i"]) {
            NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f5"];
            [friArray addObject:faj];
        }

        [day1 setObject:friArray forKey:@"frArr"];

        NSLog(@"friarray::%@", friArray);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load friArray as NSMutableArray from NSUser Defaults before the if-else ladder
2. Save the friArray in NSUSerDefaults at the end of your if-else
   ladder
3. Do not create array in every conditional statement
4. Create once in the first time(First time to store in NSUserDefaults).

   `if([day1 objectForKey:@"frArr"] == nil) {`

   ```
    // create array here.Happens first time. 
       friArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   }
   ```

Comment: thanx for the guidance. I have edited my question. Please check as I am getting friarray::(null)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try This....

```
    friArray =//Load as NSMutableArray from NSUserDefaults Dictionary for some key

    if(!friArray)friArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if ([day isEqualToString:@"f"]) {

            if ([name isEqualToString:@"f"]) {

                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f1"];
                [friArray addObject:faj];
            }
            else if ([name isEqualToString:@"z"]) {

                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f2"];
                [friArray addObject:faj];
            }
            else if ([name isEqualToString:@"a"]) {

                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f3"];
                [friArray addObject:faj];
            }
            else if ([name isEqualToString:@"m"]) {

                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f4"];
                [friArray addObject:faj];
            }
            else if ([name isEqualToString:@"i"]) {

                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f5"];
                [friArray addObject:faj];
            }

        }
    //set friArray as NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults Dictionary for some key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)addData{  
   NSMutableDictionary *fridict
     = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; 

    if ([day isEqualToString:@"f"]) {

            if ([name isEqualToString:@"f"]) {
                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f1"];
    [fridict setObject: faj forKey:@"f1"];
                       }
            else if ([name isEqualToString:@"z"]) {
                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f2"];
                [fridict setObject: faj forKey:@"f2"];
            }
            else if ([name isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f3"];
                [fridict setObject: faj forKey:@"f3"];
            }
            else if ([name isEqualToString:@"m"]) {
                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f4"];
                [fridict setObject: faj forKey:@"f4"];
            }
            else if ([name isEqualToString:@"i"]) {
                NSString *faj = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"f5"];
                [fridict setObject: faj forKey:@"f5"];
            }

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: fridict];
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:data forKey:@"fridict"];
}

-(void)retriveData{
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"fridict"];
        NSMutableDictionary *fridict = [NSKeyedUnarchiver  unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
        NSString *faj = [fridict objectForKey:@"f1"];

}
```